# Cannot run csv module on Python 3.7/Spyder/Anaconda

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to open a CSV file on Python 3.7/Spyder/Anaconda IDE.

I want to learn how to import csv files either by using pandas and by using the csv libraries.

The following code worked well and a *csvfile* variable containing the data frame was created:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Documents\PyLearning\data_file.csv', sep=',')
```

However I didn't get the same result with the csv module. After running the following code, nothing happend.

```
import csv
csvfile = open('data_file.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

I got no error message but no variable was created.

I would like to some help to understand why this is happening.

EDIT: It seems csv module was replaced by unicodecsv module at more recent python versions
https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of using pandas' read_csv is that it automatically and most importantly **quickly** converts said csv into a usable dataframe.

using csv.reader simply refers to the csv in question but you would have to call an iterator to get a result.

i.e.: (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was getting trouble with the iteration but I wasn't realizing its role to the import process.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for how to use a builtin Python module (the `csv` module, for example), I would recommend looking at the official Python documentation.

You can find the documentation for the csv module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Here's the first example they give of reading a csv file (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples):

```py
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

In the loop, you can access `row` to store it in whatever data structure you prefer.

For example, to put it in all in a list:

```py
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]
print(data)
```